# Formatting phones to E.164

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I'm trying to validate a phone number in the `E.164` format using a RegEx, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the RegEx:

`java
Pattern e164p = Pattern.compile('\+?\d{10,14}');`

Error message:

```
Error: Compile Error: Invalid string literal '\+?\d{10,14}'. Illegal character sequence '\+' in string literal.
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double escape your backslash literals: `Pattern.compile('\\+?\\d{10,14}');`

(first, the double backslash sequence will be parsed on creation of the string primitive to a literal backslash, then the literal backslash escapes the `+` and `d` in your regular expression as you intend)

Comment: Thanks, working. I guess I'm too much used to PHP and JavaScript, where we normally use `/\+?\d{10,14}/`.

Comment: Regular expressions rock as first class citizens in JS :-( I miss them too!